# Hudson not building after svn commit

Tags: svn, hudson

I set up hudson on a Windows Vista machine - running as a service.  It was working fine, but recently it seems not to build after a commit.  It never leaves the "pending" state.

When I browse to the hudson project page it seems "stuck" in the quiet period - it knows there was a commit, but it is not building yet.  My quiet period is set for 20 minutes or so, but it goes days without building in spite of commits.

I have two different queit periods - one for the global hudson install and one for this project.

Has anyone seen this problem before and is there a fix?

Comment: Have you checked the logs for exceptions? Have you restarted the service?

Comment: restarted service - it looks like Michael Donohue has the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you change the SCM polling schedule recently?   It's a known issue that the polling needs to happen less frequently than the quiet period.   See [Hudson issue 2180](https://hudson.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2180)

Comment: This definitely fixed the problem.  Thanks